# How to have different functions execute when tapped at different parts of the View?

Tags: swift, parsing, uitouch

I have a view (Circles) that displays a group of circles at different coordinates. I have loaded the coordinates of the circles through a single parse query. I am able to add a tap gesture recognizer that executes a function when the view (Circles) is tapped.

(E.g. If i tap on one of the circles, all the circles change from color blue to red)

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to have different functions execute depending on the circle (different coordinates) I tap on, rather than having a function execute in unison whenever any circle is tapped.

(E.g. If I tap on the circle at the top-left corner, it turns blue to green, while if I tap on the circle at the bottom-left corner it turns from blue to red)

I am thinking of having a system that does a function if the tapped coordinate is x and y and so on. However, I do not know how to go about it as of yet and would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

The easy (and elegant) way to do this is to make each circle its own view, and give each one its own tap gesture handler. However, if you want to keep your current approach, draw each circle as a `UIBezierPath`, which has a `containsPoint()` method that you can use for hit testing.